# "Missing locale data" when using pipe in component

Tags: angular, localization, locale

I'm stuck on this problem. I have followed the documentation and declared the locale like this in module.ts (I'm making a library):

`import localeNo from '@angular/common/locales/nb';`

Then registered it like this:

`registerLocaleData(localeNo, 'nb');`

Using the pipe in my code like this works when testing it locally:

```
const percent = this.percent.transform(
      this.employeePercent,
      '1.3-3',
      'nb');
```

But when building it (Angular CLI 9.1.0) I get the dreaded:

`ERROR Error: "InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "nb".' for pipe 't'"`

I've tried to declare the locale in my module providers like this too:

```
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'nb' },
    CurrencyPipe,
    PercentPipe
  ],
```

And I still get the error.

Comment: What happens when you use it directly in the template?

Comment: I haven't tried that. But should that give a different result? This code of mine actually does work when building the library and integrating the library in another Angular project locally. But the issue arises when I publish the Angular project that uses this library. Then is doesn't find the locale data for some reason. Even though when I import the locale in my component ```import localeNo from '@angular/common/locales/nb';``` and console log ```this.localeNo```  I can see the locale data.

Answer (score 0):

The minification removed the registerLocal() call. So I moved it into the contructor and then it works.